# How to add existing objects to relation in Parse.com Databrowser

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have created two classes in the data browser. They are named Product and ProductType. It is a many-to-many relationship so it uses a relation type. I have read that it is only possible to add and remove objects from a relation through the data browser.

But what I want is to "connect" a product to an existing product type. The product types only has 4 different rows. So it is like a "tag" static list.

How am I supposed to do that when I am unable to edit the objectId field in parse.com data browser? Or are there something that I have misunderstood?

Comment: So you're trying to edit in the data browser or in any way (REST / iOS SDK)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add a many to many relation in the data browser. I had the same problem so that I wrote a ViewController in my App to add objects to the relations.